# Converting a data.frame to an adjacency matrix for network analysis (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, adjacency-matrix, network-analysis

I want to transform the data presented below into an adjacency matrix in order to use it for network analysis.

The variables are as follows:

- `ccode1`: state number of country 1
- `ccode2`: state number of country 2
- `year` - Year of observation
- `DR_at_1` - Diplomatic representation level of side 2 at side 1 (see below)
- `DR_at_2` - Diplomatic representation level of side 1 at side 2 (see below)
- `DE` - Any diplomatic exchange between side 1 and side 2 (see below)
- `version` - Current version of the data set

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  ccode1 ccode2  year DR_at_1 DR_at_2    DE version
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1      2     20  1920       0       0     0   2006.
2      2     20  1925       0       0     0   2006.
3      2     20  1930       0       2     1   2006.
4      2     20  1935       2       2     1   2006.
5      2     20  1940       2       2     1   2006.
6      2     20  1950       9       9     1   2006.
```

Instead of this representation I want the following:

```
                         country1
country2   1'    2'      3'       4'      5'    6'    
1          0     1       0        0       0     0   
2          1     0       1        0       0     0   
3          0     0       0        0       1     1   
4          1     0       1        0       1     1   
5          0     1       0        0       0     1   
6          0     0       1        0       1     0
```

Please note that the values of this table are hypothetical.

I am new to R, which is why I am confused about how to treat the 'year' variable in this context. My intuition is that the adjacency table should be constructed individually for each year, but I am open to other suggestions.

The values of the adjacency table should be based on whether country2/1 has any diplomatic representation in country1/2 (`DR_at_1 > 0` or `DR_at_2 > 0`).

The data I use can be located in a reproducible way at the following web-address: http://www.correlatesofwar.org/data-sets/diplomatic-exchange

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Approach

This is not a hard task, given the format of data you already have. Below is an example using a special matrix indexing format - when the elements from the matrix are selected by providing another matrix (a matrix of indices) specifying each element by (row, column) pairs.

To better understand this indexing format read `help("[")`:

```
...
A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one
column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then
selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector.
...
```

#### Example

Given a toy dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(code1=1:6, code2=c(2,3,2,2,6,1), year=1990+1:6,
                 DR_at_1=c(0,0,0,2,2,9), DR_at_2=c(0,0,2,2,2,9))

df
  code1 code2 year DR_at_1 DR_at_2
1     1     2 1991       0       0
2     2     3 1992       0       0
3     3     2 1993       0       2
4     4     2 1994       2       2
5     5     6 1995       2       2
6     6     1 1996       9       9
```

We can obtain a list of relevant edges:

```
edges <- df[df$DR_at_1 > 0 | df$DR_at_2 > 0,]
edges <- cbind(as.character(edges$code1), as.character(edges$code2))
edges <- rbind(edges, edges[,2:1])  # for each edge (u,v) add a symetric edge (v,u)

edges
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "3"  "2"
[2,] "4"  "2"
[3,] "5"  "6"
[4,] "6"  "1"
[5,] "2"  "3"
[6,] "2"  "4"
[7,] "6"  "5"
[8,] "1"  "6"
```

First construct an empty adjacency matrix with country codes as row-names and col-names:

```
codes <- unique(c(df$code1, df$code2))  # All available country codes
A <- matrix(0, nrow=length(codes), ncol=length(codes), dimnames=list(codes, codes))

A
  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And finally add the needed edges to the matrix:

```
A[edges] <- 1

A
  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 1 1 0 0
3 0 1 0 0 0 0
4 0 1 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 0 0 1
6 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

#### Year Variable

In general the question about how to treat the year variable is about the context of the problem, and not about programming. You should decide about this based on the prior information you have about your problem.

Then, if you would like to have a separate adjacency matrix by year, add another filter step in the edge selection stage:

```
# Get a list of edges
edges <- df[(df$DR_at_1 > 0 | df$DR_at_2 > 0) & df$year == 1990,]
```